# Is 'parents' singular?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

A quote from [GoodRead](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/parents-and-children?page=2):

> “It's easy to be **a good parents** to a good child, but what makes you **a good parents** when you don't give up being parent to a challenging child” - *"Beta" Metani' Marashi*

Enlighten me please.

Comment: The sentence is incorrect.  *Parents* is always plural; the singular is *parent*.

Comment: Here are [a few more quotes from the same author(?)](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/14025163._Beta_Metani_Marashi) to see that the English grammar is not her forte.

Comment: Yep, see her _This book help you to thing and Stay positive!_ for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on faulty English.

Comment: *“Humans need a tune up just like cars do. Our bodies can take so much then gives up on us. Did you know that people who takes vacations get less sick then people who works two jobs and cant' afforted to take vacations? Just wondering if big Companies and Corporations knows that is cheaper for them to pay one week vacation for their employees then pay their hospital bills?"*  Jesus H Christ on a crutch.

Answer (score 2):

No, parents is never singular.

You could write

> It's easy to be a good parent to a good child, but what makes you a good parent is when you don't give up being a parent to a challenging child.

or you could write

> It's easy to be good parents to a good child, but what makes you good parents is when you don't give up being parents to a challenging child

Neither sentence is very well written even so because the word 'but' implies a contrast between the phrases on either side which is not actually expressed. "It's easy to be good parents" does not contrast with "what makes you good parents"